# Error: no viable overloaded operator[]

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a bit of my code:

```
#include "pugi/pugixml.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
int main() {
    pugi::xml_document doca, docb;
    std::map<std::string, pugi::xml_node> mapa, mapb;

    if (!doca.load_file("a.xml") || !docb.load_file("b.xml"))
        return 1;

    for (auto& node: doca.child("site_entries").children("entry")) {
        const char* id = node.child_value("id");
        mapa[new std::string(id, strlen(id))] = node;
    }

    for (auto& node: docb.child("site_entries").children("entry"))
        const char* idcs = node.child_value("id");
        std::string id = new std::string(idcs, strlen(idcs));
        if (!mapa.erase(id)) {
            mapb[id] = node;
        }
    }
```

When compiling I get this error:

```
src/main.cpp:16:13: error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'std::map<std::string, pugi::xml_node>'
        mapa[new std::string(id, strlen(id))] = node;
```

Comment: `new std::string...` --> `std::string`

Comment: Are you java man? Because  I feel Java here: `std::string id = new std::string(idcs, strlen(idcs));` . You don't `new` local variables in C++.

Comment: Nowadays, you don't `new` *anything* in C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a type mismatch. `mapa` is of type:

```
std::map<std::string, pugi::xml_node> mapa,
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But you're doing:

```
mapa[new std::string(id, strlen(id))] = node;
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         string*
```

`std::map` has two overloads of `operator[]`:

```
T& operator[](const Key& );
T& operator[](Key&& );
```

In your case, `Key` is `std::string`. But you're trying to pass in `std::string*`, for which there is no conversion to `std::string` - hence you get an error for "no viable overloaded `operator[]`".

What you meant to do was:

```
mapa[id] = node;
```

Same comment for this line:

```
std::string id = new std::string(idcs, strlen(idcs));
```

C++ is not Java, you just do:

```
std::string id(idcs, strlen(idcs));
```

or simply:

```
std::string id = idcs;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to flag up these errors: ```src/main.cpp:21:24: error: use of undeclared identifier 'idcs'
        std::string id(idcs, strlen(idcs));
                       ^
src/main.cpp:23:24: error: use of undeclared identifier 'node'
            mapb[id] = node;
``` Is this related to the new code or is that a separate issue?

Comment: @Jimmy You declare it on the line before (`const char* idcs = node.child_value("id");`)?

Comment: Type mismatch.. same error. we all do silly mistakes.. Thank you :)